# How to merge two git branches entirely remotely?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-merge

I have two branches on Google cloud repository. One is stable master branch and other is feature branch in which all new changes are done.

What i have to do is to merge feature branch with master branch.

I have search on SO for merging two git branches but all solution is about to do merge locally. it seems complicated to pull down the feature branch and the stable master branch, merge them, and then push the changes back.

Is there a git command to ask a remote git server to commit a merge of two branches and can i merge two branches remotely or there is only one option to merge branches locally?

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have search on SO for merging two git branches but all solution is about to do merge locally. it seems complicated to pull down the feature branch and the stable master branch, merge them, and then push the changes back.

Actually, I think it is preferable to do all the merging locally, because if any conflicts arise then one is in a good position to handle them.  Most IDEs now have Git plugins which make it easy to resolve conflicts.

> Is there a git command to ask a remote git server to commit a merge of two branches and can i merge two branches remotely or there is only one option to merge branches locally?

As far as I know, there is no Git command to perform a remote merge.  However, most Git repositories *do* support remote merging in some form.  For example, it is possible to merge one branch into another on GitHub.  But the caveat is that there cannot be any conflicts during the merge.  The typical way to avoid such conflicts is to perform the merge locally first, then push out the feature branch.  The other requirement is that the merge must be initiated on the GitHub server.